# Can not protect endpoint - default authorization form doesn't appear

Tags: java, spring-security-rest

I implemented the very basic example of security as I could imagine - i just would like secure my rest api endpoint which is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/public")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("test1")
    public String getTest()
    {
        return "test 1";
    }
}
```

To secure this endpoint I created configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/public/test1").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin123")).roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("dan").password(passwordEncoder().encode("dan123")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("manager").password(passwordEncoder().encode("manager123")).roles("MANAGER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

If I start my application and go to `http://localhost:8080/api/public/test1` as result I see word `test 1`. Thats mean my security doesn't work, because I should got default form to put credentials. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mvcMatchers` instead of `antMatchers`. (literally replace the word antMatchers to mvcMatchers in your code). This is because antMatchers is an older option and it sometimes doesnt cover the endpoint if endpoint has a trailing `/` or something like that.